# How to align 3 views vertically with different heights

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I have a main activity that have 3 views: `toolbar`, `MainContainer`& `bottombar`

- the `toolbar` has a height of ***60dp***
- the `MainContainer` is ***match-parent***
- the `bottombar` is ***50dp***

The problem with this, the `bottombar` don't show at all, once the `MainContainer` is set to `match-parent` it fills the rest of the layout and pushing the `bottombar` out of the visible area! same thing if the height is set to `wrap-content` !! so how to solve this..!?

```
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">


  <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:background="@color/accent"/>

  <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/MainContainer"
    android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"/>

  <com.roughike.bottombar.BottomBar
    android:id="@+id/bottombar"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:layout_below="@id/MainContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use

```
 android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

> If true, makes the bottom edge of this view match the bottom edge of
>   the parent. Accommodates bottom margin.

**Try With**

```
<com.roughike.bottombar.BottomBar
    android:id="@+id/bottombar"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:layout_below="@id/MainContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_height="50dp"/>
```

**FYI**

In your **`Framelayout`** section add **`android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"`**

Comment: @SamZar Framelayout section add `android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"`

Comment: it works, Thanks :D but you should edit the answer by adding this line too `android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"`

Answer (score 1):

> MainContainer height and width = match parent and marign_bottom in mainContainer 50dp thats the height of bottom bar

```html
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/accent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/MainContainer"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"/>

    <com.roughike.bottombar.BottomBar
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:id="@+id/bottombar"
        android:layout_below="@id/MainContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:layout_height="50dp"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  tools:context="com.truiton.bottomnavigation.MainActivity">
  <include
    android:id="@+id/mainToolbar"
    layout="@menu/toolbar" />

  <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/mainFrameLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/mainToolbar"
    android:layout_above="@+id/mainBottomNavigation"
    />

  <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/mainBottomNavigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@color/bottom_navigation_view_background"
    app:itemIconTint="@menu/nav_item_color_state"
    app:itemTextColor="@menu/nav_item_color_state"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_main"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: User using `com.roughike.bottombar.BottomBar`

Comment: Ok but the align and layout settings should be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Better solution is to use LinearLayout with vertical orientation and set weight to its children. Try the below code.

```
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">


  <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:background="@color/accent"/>

  <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/MainContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"/>

  <com.roughike.bottombar.BottomBar
    android:id="@+id/bottombar"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```